# data binding email into mailto link json

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, data-binding, knockout.js

In my view page I am trying to place an email address of a user that I get from data binding using knockout.js but I am having trouble getting it to work properly.

**Code for email**

```
<a class="icon-envelope icon-white" data-bind="attr:{href:'mailto:' + Email},text:Email"></a>
```

This is what I have and the current result is: the icon then the email address next to it and when I click on the email nothing happens. Any helpful hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing a binding to a property, you typically bind by giving the property name, just like you are with the text binding:

```
data-bind="text:Email"
```

But one thing to note is the Email is an observable, and an observable is actually a method, not a string.  So if you want to start executing some javascript directly in your binding, such as concatenating "mailto:" with the value of your Email observable, you'll need to call the observable to get it's value, like this:

```
data-bind="attr:{href:'mailto:' + Email()}"
```

Another approach you might want to consider is to create a computed observable, so that you can have simpler markup.  The computed observable in your viewmodel could look like this:

```
self.EmailLink = ko.computed(function() {
    return 'mailto:' + self.Email();
});
```

Then the markup could look like this:

```
<a data-bind="attr:{href:'mailto:' + EmailLink},text:Email"></a>
```

Working fiddle with both options: http://jsfiddle.net/tlarson/tG7mg/

Comment: Thank you this worked great! I noticed that in chrome the email didn't open anything because there wasn't a default program which i set in the control panel.