# Is it possible give an href="mailto:" the value of a data-bind: text?

Tags: html, jquery, data-binding

**I am trying to give the value of an data-bind: text function to the href="mailto:" but can't seem to get it right.**

*My Code so far:*

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="mailCloseBranch" data-bind="text: closestBranch().email">someEmailFromDataBind.com
</a>
```

Replacing Value of href:

```
$("a.mailCloseBranch[href$='#']").each(function() {
  var ref = document.getElementsByClassName('mailCloseBranch')[0].value;
  var mailref = 'mailto:' + String(ref);

  this.href = this.href.replace("#", mailref);
});
```

The 'mailto:' string from **var mailref** gets insertet and the correct email is displayed in the

`<a>` element

but the value of **var ref** stays undefined which in turn leads to no link to "mailto".

Comment: Is this all client side code? Can you make a runnable snippet or jsfiddle?  Is this question almost the same question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778250/data-binding-email-into-mailto-link-json

Comment: Can you console.log console.log document.getElementsByClassName('mailCloseBranch')[0].value ?

Comment: Thank you. The linked question was exactly what i was looking for!
I am inserting snippets with Task Manager to an existing Client side Website.
Can you post your Comment as an Answer so i can upvote it and close this question?

Comment: a hyperlink doesn't have a value attribute so `document.getElementsByClassName('mailCloseBranch')[0].value` seems peculiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps these might offer some insights?

Within the bound functions you can use `this` to access the hyperlink directly and thus access it's properties rather than use `document.getElementsByClassName('mailCloseBranch')[0].value` (which would be wrong ) or `document.getElementsByClassName('mailCloseBranch')[0].textContent`

```js
// using the LINK TEXT to form part of the new href
$("a.mailCloseBranch[href$='#']").each( function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace("#", 'mailto:' + String( this.textContent ) );
});

// using the DATA.BIND attribute value to form part of the new href
$("a.mailCloseBranch-2[href$='#']").each( function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace("#", 'mailto:' + String( this.dataset.bind.replace('text:','') ) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="#" class="mailCloseBranch" data-bind="text:closestBranch().email">someEmailTextcontent.com</a> |


<a href="#" class="mailCloseBranch-2" data-bind="text:closestBranch().email">emailfromDataBind.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for my Question:**

[data binding email into mailto link json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778250/data-binding-email-into-mailto-link-json)

Posted by [jqueryHtmlCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3825777/jqueryhtmlcss)